# Clear focus from EditText on button click - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-widget, android-textinputedittext, onfocuschangelistener

- There are total 5 EditTexts.
- I'm calling one method in **setOnFocusChangeListener** of an EditText i.e **txt_location**.
- While I click on **SAVE AND CONTINUE** button I'm validating all EditTexts.
- When I click on **SAVE AND CONTINUE** button **txt_location - EditText** automatically gaining focus which I don't want.

What I have tried:

- **txt_location.clearFocus()**
- **other_edittext.requestFocus()**

My Code like below.

**AddAddressFragment.java**

Below methods are in **onActivityCreated** method.

```
txt_location.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {

                txt_location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        findPlace();
                    }
                });
                findPlace();
            }
        }
    });

layoutFooter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isvalidateFields()){
              // Code after validating all EditTexts
            }
        }
    });
```

Below method is outside of onActivityCreated method.

```
private boolean isvalidateFields() {
    boolean result = true;
    if (!ValidationUtils.hasText(txtCity, cityTxt, "City Required")) {
        result = false;
    }
    if (!ValidationUtils.hasText(txt_location, location_txt, "Location Required")) {
        result = false;
    }
    if (!ValidationUtils.hasText(txtPincode, pincodeTxt, "Pincode Required"))
        result = false;
    if (!ValidationUtils.hasText(txtDoorName, doorNumberTxt, "Address line 1 Required")) {
        result = false;
    }
    if (!ValidationUtils.hasText(txtApartmentName, apartmentTxt, "Address line 2 Required")) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**address_fragment.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="15px">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/titleText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/large_margin"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/normal_margin"
                        android:text="Address"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_content" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/small_margin"
                        android:button="@drawable/check_box"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:clickable="false" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/small_margin"
                    android:background="@color/gray_border" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/large_margin"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/large_margin">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/doorNumberTxt"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/txtDoorName"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/normal_margin"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:hint="@string/door_number"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:textColorHighlight="@color/gray_text"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/gray_text"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/normal_margin"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin"
                            android:background="@color/gray_border" />

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/apartmentTxt"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/txtApartmentName"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/normal_margin"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:hint="@string/apartment_number"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:textColorHighlight="@color/gray_text"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/gray_text"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/normal_margin"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin"
                            android:background="@color/gray_border" />

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/location_txt"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/txt_location"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/normal_margin"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:clickable="false"
                                android:hint="@string/txt_location"
                                android:lines="2"
                                android:textColorHighlight="@color/gray_text"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/gray_text"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/normal_margin"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin"
                            android:background="@color/gray_border" />

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/cityTxt"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/txtCity"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/normal_margin"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:clickable="false"
                                android:hint="@string/city"
                                android:lines="5"
                                android:textColorHighlight="@color/gray_text"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/gray_text"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/normal_margin"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin"
                            android:background="@color/gray_border" />

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/pincodeTxt"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/txtPincode"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/normal_margin"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:digits="1234567890"
                                android:hint="@string/pincode"
                                android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:textColorHighlight="@color/gray_text"
                                android:textColorHint="@color/gray_text"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/normal_margin"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin"
                            android:background="@color/gray_border" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutFooter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/fab_button_color">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLblInr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/x_large_margin"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/save_n_contine"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTotalContinue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/x_large_margin"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/right_arrow"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_title" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found alternate solution as **ZeroOne's** answer did not work for me. I removed **setOnFocusChangeListener** and put **setOnEditorActionListener** on an EditText which is just before **txt_location - EditText**. And I put **setOnTouchListener** to **txt_location - EditText**.

**setOnEditorActionListener** - It calls when you click NEXT LINE button on keyboard.

Full changed code is like below.

```
EditTextJustBefore_txt_location_EditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                findPlace();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    txt_location.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                findPlace();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Give Id to Your parent layout ex: LinearLayout, Then `linearLayout.requestFocus()`

and put this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" <-- add this
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" <-- add this
>

.....

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where to put `linearLayout.requestFocus()`?  I have put in `layoutFooter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (isvalidateFields()) {
                    
                } else {
                    ll_address_frag.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });`

But it is not working@ZeroOne